# How to ensure firebase sync all database before calling `process.exit()`

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running a node.js shell script to update firebase database with a series of `db.ref().set()`.

May I know how do I ensure that all the `db.ref().set()` is completely synced before calling `process.exit()` to end the shell script?

Comment: Did you try adding an onComplete in the set? [Firebase Set Docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html)

Comment: I can use a `onComplete` callback in the `set()` to keep track of the number of async `set()`, but is there a cleaner way to do, such as to check all promises at the end of say 30 `set()` and call `process.exit()` subsequently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` to achieve this:

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(ref1.set({foo: 'bar'});
promises.push(ref2.set({baz: 'qux'});

Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
  console.log('Everything completed successfully.');
  process.exit(0);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('One or more sets failed:', err.stack);
  process.exit(1);
});
```